# CSS selector for text not in tags

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to totally hide everything in the `.byline` **except** the date. Is it possible to do this via CSS w/o modifying the markup? Is there a CSS selector that allows you to target the inner text that's not in tags?

```
<p class="byline">
    By <a rel="author" href="#">John Doe</a>
    on <time datetime="2012-10-10" pubdate>2012</time>
</p>
```

This does **not** work b/c it hides the `a` but not the other text:

```
.byline :not(time) { display:none }
```

This does **not** work b/c it hides everything:

```
.byline { display:none }
.byline time { display:inline }
```

This **works** but is not ideal b/c then you have to deal with hiding the space too:

```
.byline { visibility:hidden }
.byline time { visibility:visible }
```

See: [jsfiddle.net/pxxR7/](http://jsfiddle.net/pxxR7/) and [jsfiddle.net/pxxR7/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/pxxR7/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use font-size [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ocopiq/1/edit)

```
.byline {font-size:0px; }
.byline time {font-size:15px}
```

Comment: It will still be read out by screen readers for example (so it's inaccessible) and will trigger some red flag at Google HQ, with the risk of being blacklisted (it's not certain as the blacklisting is done after a manual review following the automatic flagging by a bot, but OP would better know that he is taking a risk by doing that)

Comment: late edit: "so it's inaccessible" ==> *IF* it wasn't meant to be read out by anybody, same if CSS is disabled

Comment: @FelipeAls I agree this isn't ideal and should be used sparingly.

Answer (score 3):

CSS can only select elements, not bare text. That is the reason why `:not(time)` doesn't work (it only selects the `a`).

The reason why `display: none` and `display: inline` don't work is because `display: none` on a container prevents it and all of its contents from displaying, even if you try to set it to anything else (plus, `time` already displays `inline` by default).

Answer (score 2):

[@BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) is, of course, right that you can't select text, just elements. But, the following workaround should work:

```
.byline {
    font-size: 0px;
    color: transparent;
}
.byline time {
    font-size: medium;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: `normal` is not a valid value for `font-size`. You probably meant `medium`, or a pixel value. (Definitely not `1em` or `100%`, for obvious reasons...)

Comment: @BoltClock Yep, thank you! I always confuse `font-size` with `font-weight`.

Comment: I'd suggest also setting `color` to `transparent` for the `.byline` element (and then resetting for the elements to show), as I seem to recall IE having some issues with `0px` as a font-size.

Comment: @DavidThomas Definitely, I recall seeing such issues in IE7.

Comment: Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Vzjry/

Comment: Same problems as Champ answer (see my comment there)